# How do I get an Entity's repository from the ApplicationContext

Tags: typescript, nestjs

How do I get an Entity's repository from the ApplicationContext

```
const ctx = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule)
const repository = ctx.get<Repository<UserEntity>>(Repository);

// Error: Nest cannot find given element (it does not exist in current context)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out

```
import ...
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

const ctx = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule)
const repository: Repository<UserEntity> = ctx.get(getRepositoryToken(UserEntity));
```

Comment: you should accept your own answer as it solves the problem.